# Can't search queries in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search a query in a MySQL table called "keys" based on a key, and then return other values for that query. (e.g. "id")

This is how my table looks like:

```
id              key                          customer
88633631        gNjp4CW6E/VfdBqli6zBLw==     Name1
41317488        bi74frT3LFGTRkvoW7B31Q==     Name2
```

..and this is how my PHP code looks like:

```
<?php
    require 'config.inc.php';
    /* Declare variables */
    $key = $_GET["key"];   
    $id = "";
    $customer = "";
    /* Connect to database and grab the keys */
    @mysql_connect($g_mysql_host,$g_mysql_usr,$g_mysql_pass)
    or die("Couldn't connect to database server");
    @mysql_selectdb($g_mysql_db)
    or die("Couldn't select database");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = $key";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) exit("INVALID KEY");
    else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['id'];
        }
    }
?>
```

But this does not work. I think that the problem is caused by the 2 equals at the end of the key, but I'm not sure. 
If I want to search the "id" and then print the "key" of the searched "id", it works.

I don't want to remove the 2 equals at the end, because they are related to AES128 padding.

Actually, the problem is not caused by the 2 equals at the end of the key. It is caused by the "+" character inside the string, but if I remove it I can't decrypt the AES128 encrypted text.

Comment: `key` and `keys` are reserved words in MySQL and ***should not*** be used as table or column names. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: This script is just for personal use. It works even if the column is named "key" . I have renamed it to "lic_key" but the problem persists. This question is not duplicate, because I have a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the way you do this.

First, you don't quote your value: `'$key'`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = '$key'";
```

Second, your code is wide open to SQL injection. Escape your value:

```
$key = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["key"]);
```

The code above is the absolute minimum you need to do.
The next thing is that the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated a long time and have been removed in PHP 7.

You'll need to switch to either `mysqli_` or `PDO`. The sooner you switch, the better.
Please read this question for further information: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Apart from all the problems above, you'll save yourself (and even more so others, if they ever have to read your code) some headache if you don't ever use [keywords and reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) as table or column names, as Jay Blanchard has noted.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Yes, I've read your comment above. Is that really the problem? The columns are escape with `\``, so it should work despite being bad practice, shouldn't it?

Comment: It works, but if the key is wrong, "if (!$result) exit("INVALID KEY");" does absolutely nothing. The page is blank. And if the key contains "+" the page is blank too. I have to remove "+" to get it working, but this is not what I want, because the key can't be decrypted.

Comment: More of a caution than anything else @Pharaoh

Comment: This answer fixed one of my problems. More details about the other ones here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697754/search-base64-string-in-mysql-table-using-php/43697936#43697936 . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you didn't escaped the input it should be

```
"SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = '$key'"
```

but anyway this is not the best way to do that, you have to use prepared statement and wrapper such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Something like this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = :key');
$stmt->bindValue(":key", $_GET["key"]);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thanks. I will take these tips into consideration in the future.

Answer (score 0):

what about if you change the following line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = $key";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = '".$key."' ";
```

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).