# Search Base64 string in MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687811/cant-search-queries-in-mysql-table) yesterday, but I didn't get an answer and the question has been marked as duplicate, which is not.

I changed the "key" column name to "lic_key" and "keys" table name to "license_keys" because I understand they are reserved by MySQL.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    require 'config.inc.php';
    /* Connect to database and grab the keys */

    @mysql_connect($g_mysql_host,$g_mysql_usr,$g_mysql_pass)
    or die("Couldn't connect to database server");
    @mysql_selectdb($g_mysql_db)
    or die("Couldn't select database");
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["key"]);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `license_keys` WHERE `lic_key` = '$key'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result == "") exit("INVALID KEY");
    else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['id'];
        }
    }

?>
```

This works only if the key does NOT contain the "+" character, and it outputs the specific "id" for the searched "license_key" .
If the key contains "+" or is not found, the page remains blank (which is another problem that I have, because the script should output "INVALID KEY") .

The key strings are encrypted using AES128 in Base64. Other keys have the "+" character, other not.

Shortly,

```
kQcYqzQlsr4/MXJ1ySw7jQ==  -- works. 

CKVcua+aWlnK5qfKwcm6wA== -- does not work.
```

This script is only for personal usage, so I'm not scared about SQL injection.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with `+` is probably in the client. `+` has special meaning in URL-encoded parameters, and it needs to be encoded as `%2B`. The client probably isn't calling `encodeURIComponent()` before putting the base64 password into the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. If I replace "+" with "%2B" the script outputs the "id", so this is not a big deal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar for clarifying the problem with "+" character in the URL.
To fix the problem with the blank page if the key is incorrect, I edited

```
if ($result == "") exit("INVALID KEY");
```

with

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) exit("INVALID KEY");
```

and now it works.